# Heater warms up but won't blow, fan is good

Tags: hvac, central-heating

I have a **Lennox Whisper Heat Central Heat unit model G20Q3E-75-4** natural gas heater. It worked fine until today, and nothing has changed about the house or the heater, we have electricity and gas.

The thermostat clicks at the appropriate temperature.  Then I hear the heater click, and the burner ignites and starts to warm up.  After about a minute, when you'd expect the fan to come on, the whole thing just shuts down.   I tested the fan by turning it to cool and running the fan, and the fan works on cool.  But not on heat.   So the thermostat works, the fan works, the gas system preheats, but it just dies when it's supposed to start blowing hot air.

Any ideas anyone?

ADDENDUM:  I put this here because it's too long for a comment.
I did some more troubleshooting. If the unit is set to heat, and the thermostat set 4 degrees or so above the current temp, the igniter and valve switch on and the flame is lit.  Then it begins to heat up, but the fan never comes on.  So I guess it overheats, and something switches the unit off.  In this state, the fan won't blow, even on manual, or on AC.  Nothing.  But if I let it cool down a sit for 30 minutes or so, I can switch the fan to manual ON and the fan blows.  And, when it's not hot, the AC will work and control the fan as usual, in auto mode (and also in Manual On mode as normal).

AND, when it's cool, if I turn on the fan with Manual ON, and THEN turn on the heater, the heart heats up and runs, and the fan keeps it from overheating, and we're all good, except the fan is on Manual ON not auto, so when the heater reaches the desired temperature, the heat goes off but the fan is still in manual.

The only thing not working is the fan won't come on in Heat mode.  But the fan works in every other thing I've tried, including A/C, AND it works with heat but only in Manual ON mode.

Comment: Imagine a wire loose or broken, or a sensor, on the heat circuit for fan.

Comment: I've had similar symptoms when a flame sensor was dirty or damaged. After that minute, the flame sensor checks to see if the flame is present. If it doesn't sense a flame, the heater shuts down. That would seem to match your symptoms. Check your flame sensor.

Comment: Please revise to tell us more than "a heater". Brand and model would be great.

Comment: What make and model is said heater?

Comment: It's a Lennox Whisper Heat Central Heat unit model G20Q3E-75-4